# Does the series admit a limit as $\alpha\to 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have the following problem:

Let $\{x_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers and let $\sigma_n=\sigma_n(\alpha)$ be a sequence of weights, depending on a real parameter $\alpha>0$, such that $\sigma_n>0$, $$\sum_{n\geq 1} \sigma_n<\infty$$ for all $\alpha>0$ and $\sigma_n\to 1$ as $\alpha\to 0$. To fix ideas, consider
$$ \sigma_n = \frac{1}{1+\alpha n^2},$$
but I would like to know if there are results more in general, for $\sigma_n$ satisfying the properties above. Now, by the hypothesis we know that
$$\sum_{n\geq 1} \sigma_n x_n$$
is absolutely convergent for any $\alpha>0$. What I'm interested in is understanding if the following rescaled series admits limit as $\alpha\to 0$:
$$\lim_{\alpha\to 0} \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{n\geq 1} \sigma_n x_n}{\displaystyle \sum_{n\geq 1} \sigma_n}.$$
My intuition tells me that, since $\sigma_n\to 1$ as $\alpha\to 0$, it will tend to some sort of uniform distribution, i.e.
$$\lim_{\alpha\to 0} \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{n\geq 1} \sigma_n x_n}{\displaystyle \sum_{n\geq 1} \sigma_n} 
= \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N x_n,$$
assuming the RHS is well defined. So the question is: is my intuition correct? Or is it correct under suitable assumptions on $\{x_n\}_n$ or $\{\sigma_n(\alpha)\}$?

This is not an exercise, it's something that has come up in a project I'm working on, and usually I don't deal with this type of problems so I don't know how to approach it. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: when I talk about assumptions on $\sigma_n$ I mean possiblle assumptions in addition to the ones I'm already imposing. Moreover, I'm more interested in understanding if the limit exists and what it looks like, rather then force the assumptions in order to make it become what my intuition tells me it should be. To make it clear: I'm mainly interested in the case
$$\sigma_n=\frac{1}{1+\alpha n^2}$$
but there are lots of other choices of $\sigma_n$ which satisfy the assumptions, as for example
$$\sigma_n=\frac{1}{1+\alpha n^c}\ \text{ for some } c>1$$
but also things like
$$\sigma_n=\frac{1}{1+\alpha n!}$$
with the latter example decaying much faster then the others. So I'm trying to understand what would be the limit of the ratio in the first example, and if it would change taking the other choices or it would be still the same.

Comment: You have said that $\sigma_n \to 1$ as $\alpha \to 0$. If this convergence holds uniformly with respect to $n$ then the series $\sum \sigma_n$ won't converge and the inequality you have conjectured does not make sense.  $\sigma_n$ has to $ \to 1$ 'very badly'  for the inequality to even make sense.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes obviously when I say $\sigma_n\to 1$ I mean pointwise, i.e. for any fixed $n$, $\sigma_n(\alpha)\to 1$ as $\alpha\to 0$. It seemed quite clear from the context and the example of $\sigma_n$ I’ve given

Comment: Sorry about that. But note that the result you want is an identity when $\sigma_n=1$ for all n. To me the case $\sum \sigma_n =\infty$ looks more interesting and also likely to be true.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. I'll edit the question to make it clear what I'm asking and what I'd like to understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't seen it already, take a quick look at the Wikpiedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series, and Hardy's book "Divergent series". There is a notational difference between series (as in summability theory) and sequences (as in your question), but it is easy to translate between the two.

If $x_n$ converges to a limit $x,$ then by the (easy direction of the) [Silverman-Toeplitz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverman%E2%80%93Toeplitz_theorem) your rescaled limit converges to the same value $x$; use $a_{i,j}=\sigma_j(\alpha_i)/\sum_{n\geq 1}\sigma_n$ for a sequence $\alpha_i\to 0.$ So we're dealing with a "regular" matrix method. Well, sort of - "matrix methods" require $\alpha$ to be discrete.

For $x_n$ not necessarily convergent, if the weights $\sigma_n$ are non-increasing for each $\alpha,$ and the Cesàro mean $x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\tfrac 1N\sum_{n=1}^N x_n$ exists, then the rescaled limit is the same value $x.$ So your rescaled series is "consistent with" the Cesàro mean. To show this, let $m_n=\tfrac 1N\sum_{n=1}^N x_n$ and write $\sum_{n\geq 1}\sigma_nx_n$ as $\sum_{n\geq 1}(\sigma_n-\sigma_{n+1})nm_n.$ The values $(\sigma_n-\sigma_{n+1})n$ are non-negative, and $m_n\to x,$ so by the Silverman-Toeplitz theorem your rescaled limits tend to $x$; use $a_{i,j}=(\sigma_n-\sigma_{n+1})nm_n/\sum_{n\geq 1}\sigma_n.$

Comment: Thanks a lot! As i said I never encountered this type of problems, so I didn't know any of this stuff. This is definitely an answer worth the bounty, but I'll need a bit of time to check the references you've given me before assigning it to you. A  few questions: 1) just to be sure, so such reasoning holds for all the examples of $\sigma_n$ given above right? 2) if I didn't have the cesaro limit for $x_n$ but an even weaker one, like a Fejer limit, i.e. $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N m_n\to x$ with $m_n$ as above, can still something be said? Feels like there is a recursive argument but I'm not sure

Comment: @Lucio: (1) yes, your example $\sigma_n$ are non-increasing. (2) I don't think that's called a Fejer limit - it's the Holder sum "$(H,2)$", equivalent to the generalized Cesàro sum "$(C,2).$" I don't know how your examples relate to $(C,2)$ summability, but in principle you can compare any two weighted means to see if they are compatible - see ["Classical and Modern Methods in Summability", Johann Boos, Theorem 3.2.8](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kZ9cy6XyidEC&lpg=PA114&vq=theorem%203.2.8&pg=PA114#v=snippet&q=theorem%203.2.8&f=false)

Comment: Yes sorry, I called it "Fejer limit" in analogy to Fourier series, but it's not a real name. Just tell me it this sounds reasonable to you: so if $\sigma_n$ are decreasing and $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N m_n\to x$ by what we said above $\sum\sigma_n m_n / \sum\sigma_n \to x$. So now can we apply the same trick as before, i.e. write $x_n$ in function of $m_n$, to obtain the limit for $\sum\sigma_n x_n / \sum\sigma_n \to x$? It seems to me that we can if we assume the "new weights" $\widetilde{\sigma_n}:=n(\sigma_n - \sigma_{n+1})$ to be decreasing as well. Do you think it works?

Comment: @Lucio: it sounds reasonable though I'm not sure how useful that condition will be for you. Using the $(C,2)$ condition instead, I think it suffices for $\sigma_n-\sigma_{n+1}$ to be decreasing, i.e. $\sigma_n$ is convex. But $1/(1+\alpha n^2)$ is strictly concave when $n$ and $\alpha$ are small.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! You’ve given me a lot of material to work on. If you have any other reference or something else comes on your mind you’re welcome to write it, but it should already be enough :)